# Firefox render error inside perspective element

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing an error in Firefox with elements that flip on hover. (The error can be seen in the attached screenshot).

The elements are css only, using box shadow, border-radius and things like

```
(*-)transform-style: preserve-3d;                   
(*-)transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.8,.1,.3,.9);
(*-)perspective: 600px;
(*-)transform: rotateY( 0deg );
```

I could not find out why this error occurs, any ideas?

[image: Error, flip-able cards]

Additionally sometimes there is an error with the shadow.

[image]

Cheers,
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed with the new Firefox build.